# Convert pyarrow timestamp in ms to BigQuery timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp, pyarrow

I have my timestamp in `pyarrow` in `ms` with this value: '2010-01-30 00:00:00.000000000'. I'm trying to convert it into a format that BigQuery will accept. I've tried:

- `SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%F %H:%M:%E*S %Ez", "2010-01-30 00:00:00.000000000") AS parsed;`
- `SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%c", "2010-01-30 00:00:00.000000000") AS parsed;`

but get the same error:

```
Failed to parse input string
```

I tried:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP("2010-01-30 00:00:00.000000000");
```

got:

```
Invalid timestamp: '2010-01-30 00:00:00.000000000'
```

Tried:

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%c", TIMESTAMP "2010-01-30 00:00:00.000000000", "UTC") AS formatted;
```

Got:

```
Invalid TIMESTAMP literal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query worked for me:

```sql
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%F %H:%M:%E*S", "2010-01-30 00:00:00.000000000") AS parsed;
```

Output:

[image]